# Laravel redirect inside of Trait

Tags: php, laravel

```
trait foo{

    public function bar()
    {
         redirect('/'); //not working
    }
}

use Traits;

class DonController extend Controller{
     use Traits\foo;

     $this->bar();
     redirect('/'); //working
}
```

I'm new in Laravel, I need to create a redirect method inside of trait

However I have problem to do it inside of trait. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only a controller method can return a redirect object to go to another page. You can however invoke the `->send()` method of a redirect object to send the redirect directly from anywhere in your application.

```
trait foo {

    public function bar()
    {
         redirect('/')->send();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thx a lot! that save my ass, i really need this be inside of trait, so i can reuse for most of pages

Comment: I don't know exactly how you are using this, but it might be a good idea to take a look at [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

Comment: my app need to connect to REST api, and I need to set up a redirect method if any error happen. Its much ezer for me to create this in trait so all controllers can use it

Comment: In my case I have to save an answer, from 12 posible (views), that go to one column in the DB. It is a survey. So I don't want to repeat that code 12 times, that's why I use a Trait, where, depending on the answer chosen, it should redirect to a specific route. I don't know whether this is a good approach or not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I tried using this method in my project but unfortunately the redirect does not register as a 302 but a 200 status code. This causes tests which check for status 302 redirects to fail. Any suggestion how to fix this?