# Laravel - Redirect on model constructor

Tags: laravel, redirect, model

I have a Laravel project with some model which have been pointed to external databases (from Magento). On the constructor of this models I want to check a session variable in order to change the model connection to the user selection. One of this checks must be if the user selected some external platform, for connecting to this, if not I wanna redirect to the selection page. I am trying with this to avoid session expiration and manual route writing (without platform selection).

How can I redirect the user to certain page in the model constructor?

Main Model

```
class MagentoModel extends Model
{
    protected $platform;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->platform = app('selectedPlatform');
        if ($this->platform->id < 1) {
            return redirect()->route('index');
            // Maybe I have to use Redirect::route('index');
        }
    }
}
```

Certain model extending MagentoModel

```
class Customer extends MagentoModel
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->connection = $this->platfom->connection_key;
        $this->table = config('customersTable');
    }
}
```

It throws an error right now:

> Trying to get property 'connection_key' of non-object

I supose the parent constructor (MagentoModel) is not being executed before the line `$this->connection = $this->platfom->connection_key;`. Is possible my OOP comprehension is not right just in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect inside of Trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371728/laravel-redirect-inside-of-trait)

Comment: You are completely right, could be duplicate I will try that solution. Thanks. Could you say something about the error?

Comment: Is checked and solved. Thanks a lot @Jerodev